# Only part of vimrc is read in Fedora

Tags: vim

I just installed Fedora in a virtual machine, and when I open vim, my vimrc is only being partially read. That is, some of the settings are set, but others are not. It's vim version 7.3.515.

For example, settings such as turning on line numbers work, but `let mapleader = ","` is not setting the comma as the leader character. (In fact, backslash doesn't work either).

Also, my color scheme isn't being loaded:

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set t_Co=256
endif

if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme wombat
elseif &t_Co == 256
    colorscheme wombat256
endif
```

These work fine in gvim however. This is the same vimrc I use on all of my machines, so I'm really at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did find out the exact cause, but `$ yum install vim` did the trick. It was the same version as the one already installed; maybe it was compiled with different options.

Answer (score 2):

```
:set ft=vim
gg=G
```

After re-indenting your code:

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set t_Co=256
    if has("gui_running")
        colorscheme wombat
    elseif &t_Co == 256
        colorscheme wombat256
    endif
```

---

`if...endif` doesn't match!
You need to add `endif` to close `if` statement.

Comment: Oops, well spotted! That was just a copy/paste error; it's correct in the actual vimrc. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Please use this command to open vim: `vim -V20log +q`. Then open the `log` file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, but I can't see anything in the log that could be causing my problem: http://pastebin.com/QJHyVYSs